# Result on execution of any SQL is number 2

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, sqlplus

After successful execution of any sql in oracle sql command line it shows 2
like i want to see the table or description of any table it show 2 instead of showing the table.

```
SQL> select * from dual
  2
SQL> select * from user_objects
  2
SQL>
```

Comment: Also see [Running SQL\*Plus Commands](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#i1039736), and more specifically [Ending a SQL Command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#sthref273)

Answer (score 8):

You need to terminate the SQL statement with a semicolon (`;`) or a put a slash (`/`) in the new line instead of hitting Enter. For example: `select * from dual;`. Otherwise SQLPlus will believe you have not finished your SQL statement, and it starts counting the lines. `2` is actually a line number, it is the 2nd line of your SQL statement. If you type nothing here and just hit `Enter`, SQL*Plus will terminate your statement and return the prompt, it can not handle empty lines.